# How to solve error C2719 in visual studio 2010 c++ when no code line exist in code

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am building a project I have received from a colleague. I am receiving the following error:

> ..\HelperFunctions\disp.cpp(130): error C2719: 'viewpoint': formal parameter with __declspec(align('16')) won't be aligned

I am following clues to `disp.cpp` line 130 only to find this is the end of a function and all I have in this line is:

```
}
```

Following [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/85e53fd8-9345-42d2-bfa1-1ce4ee4e4c68/error-c2719-a-formal-parameter-with-declspecalign16-wont-be-aligned?forum=vclanguage) it is my understanding this might be an issue with the function definition, but I could not fully understand if there is anything wrong. I have commented all unnecessary elements of the function and reduced it to:

```
std::vector< int > HPR (typename pcl::PointCloud<PointT>::ConstPtr source,pcl::PointXYZ viewpoint, double param)
{
    //commented section
    std::vector< int > indices;
    //commented section
    return indices;
}
```

Still getting the same error.

- What am I missing?
- How do I address this?

P.S.
I am new to C++ and working on visual studio 2010 with [PCL API](http://pointclouds.org/).

Comment: Have you looked at definition of `pcl::PointXYZ`?

Comment: yes. I am not sure though, what am I looking for on the definition of `pcl::PointXYZ`? Also why then would it give the error at the end of the function? Is that a normal behavior?

Comment: I suspect that `pcl::PointXYZ` requires special memory alignment of the data. (I once saw this in the [Eigen library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigen_(C%2B%2B_library)) where it was needed in conjunction with some [SSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) stuff.) How to fix it? I would try this: using `const pcl::PointXYZ &viewport` instead of `pcl::PointXYZ viewpoint` as formal parameter. A pointer might do as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After googling the [`pcl::PointXYZ`](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.0.1/point__types_8hpp_source.html), I found out that it's actually based on the [Eigen library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigen_(C%2B%2B_library)). (I saw a lot of `EIGEN` macros in the source code.)

The EIGEN library tries to obtain best performance using special [SSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) instructions. AFAIK, these SSE instructions require that the data has to be aligned appropriately (e.g. that addresses are multiples of 16).

This may interfere with the passing of function arguments for

```
std::vector<int> HPR(
  typename pcl::PointCloud<PointT>::ConstPtr source,
  pcl::PointXYZ viewpoint, double param);
```

When a function is called the arguments may be handed over in CPU registers but usually (especially on Intels x86 CPUs) they are pushed to the stack where the function accesses them using a certain base pointer, for Intels CPUs e.g. obtaining the BP register (16 bit), EBP (32 bit), or RBP (64 bit).

More about this on Eli Benderskys [Stack frame layout on x86-64](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/06/stack-frame-layout-on-x86-64).

However, pushing data to stack may not allow to align the data as required (without breaking the "binary signature" of the called function). Thus, the compiler throws the error C2719.

If the 2<sup>nd</sup> parameter of the function is changed from value to reference this means the reference of the original variable is handed over. (Although this may technically not fully correct, I imagine it as handing over the address of the original variable instead of a copy on stack.) To prevent accidental overwriting the contents of the referenced variable, a `const` reference can be used:

```
std::vector<int> HPR(
  typename pcl::PointCloud<PointT>::ConstPtr source,
  const pcl::PointXYZ &viewpoint, double param);
```

Due to the reference, the original variable is used which is either correcly aligned (or would cause another error at another line of source code). For the reference, no special alignment is required anymore.

To use a `const` (or non-`const`) reference instead of a value may have additionally a positive performance effect. If the parameter type is something with significant greater size than a "machine word" (i.e. something which fits into a register) than it is worth to pass the reference instead of copying the value. This is probably the case for [`pcl::PointXYZ`](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.0.1/point__types_8hpp_source.html) considering:

```
#define PCL_ADD_POINT4D \
  EIGEN_ALIGN16 \
  union { \
    float data[4]; \
    struct { \
      float x; \
      float y; \
      float z; \
    }; \
  } ;
```

...

```
struct _PointXYZ
{
  PCL_ADD_POINT4D;  // This adds the members x,y,z which can also be accessed using the point (which is float[4])
  EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW;
};
```

and

```
struct EIGEN_ALIGN16 PointXYZ : public _PointXYZ
```

(According to `float[4]`, it should consume 16 bytes.)

In oppisition, it's not worth to consider a reference for primitive types like `bool`, `int`, and any pointer (which usually should fit into "machine word" width).

Comment: Your comment about size is questionable: having to double dereference *and* invalidate cached copies whenever you have nonlocal code can easily cost you more than pushing 32 to 64 more bits on the stack.

Comment: @Yakk To squeeze out the very last performance bit, seems to me like black magic. I agree with you (and am glad that I formulated everything very carefully e.g. with "may" and "significant greater size"). But if you would prove me really hard I will probably lose. Beside of this, I consider it more worth to optimize the software design on a high level. Once you try to earn something by "turning the screws" on that CPU register level, it usually becomes really hard... (...and questionable whether it ever will pay off.)

Comment: @Yakk Out of curiosity: If a value is provided by copy instead of by reference, doesn't it mean that the same potential cache misses may happen (but this time on caller side i.e. when value is loaded on stack)?

Comment: Not CPU cache, but things like loading the values into a register.  References are hard to reasona about compared to values on the stack, so knowing when you have to recheck the value as opposed to just uae the value cached in a register is easier when you pass by value.  My point is that the size of the object on the stack shouldn't be a hard cutoff for pass by value.