# How to solve error C2719 in visual studio 2010 when compiling a cpp generated by cython

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, std, eigen, cythonize

I'm trying to install a python module to use the PCL library (wrote in C++ and using the Eigen library) following this procedure : https://github.com/strawlab/python-pcl

Unfortunately when I'm trying to build the septup file I get the C2719 error (see screenshoot for detail). [png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fo2x.png)

The line code causing the error is the following :

```
    __pyx_vtable_3pcl_4_pcl_OctreePointCloudSearch._VoxelSearch = (void (*)(struct __pyx_obj_3pcl_4_pcl_OctreePointCloudSearch *,  struct pcl::PointXYZ, std::vector<int>  &))__pyx_f_3pcl_4_pcl_22OctreePointCloudSearch__VoxelSearch;
```

(for detail code see https://pastebin.com/W0m9wzzc)

After reading about this : https://ofekshilon.com/2010/05/05/stdvector-of-aligned-elements/

I understand that i have to adapt the syntax of the code to make it explicit that objects are aligned on a 16 byte boundaries.

My issue is clearly of the same kind of that one : [How to solve error C2719 in visual studio 2010 c++ when no code line exist in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471818/how-to-solve-error-c2719-in-visual-studio-2010-c-when-no-code-line-exist-in-co)

I can more or less assume that the part of the code causing the problem is related to `struct pcl::PointXYZ, std::vector<int>  &)`

Unfortunately I'm completely new to C++ and I do not really understand what the code is doing, thus I'm unable to adapt it to make it work.

Help would be greatly appreciate :)

spec:
Cython 0.25.2
PCL 1.6
VS 2010